Hash function to decorrelate datasets
Consider three sets of data A, B and C. mutual information I(A:B)=I(A:C). Now I apply hashing function to A to obtain a new data A' with entropy H(A|B). does that imply I(A':C)=0.

Do I understand it correctly that after the Hashing you get $H(A') = H(A|B)$ ?
If this is correct, it would be good to give some details of your hashing function. If not, please clarify what exactly you mean.
